# float right element inverted

Tags: html, css

In my header I have 4 elements which are:

"Running Days" - "admin@email.com" - "Deposit" - "Paidout".

My 4 elements are separated into 2.
"Deposit" and "Paidout" are in right in my header.

I made a `float:right`! 
Except that the order is inverted namely I have "Paidout" before "Deposit".

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: #CEECE8;
}

.subtitles {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.subtile-left {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 18px;
}

.subtile-right {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 18px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="subtitles">
    <div class="subtile-left"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i> 137 Running Days </div>
    <div class="subtile-left"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i> Admin@superbtc.biz </div>
    <div class="subtile-right"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Deposit </div>
    <div class="subtile-right"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Paidout </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Elements are floated in order of source appearance.

Comment: @connexo: I don't understand :-(

Comment: Added an answer with explanations. Let me know if anything remains unclear.

Comment: Is your question "*what's going on here*" or is it "*how do I fix it*"? Means: You want a working solution, or you want to understand the problem so you can address it yourself?

Comment: @connexo my problem is solved now. mercy

Comment: You haven't answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `float:left` with the left elements instead and adjust `text-align` to align the other to the right:

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: #CEECE8;
}

.subtitles {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align:right; 
}

.subtile-left {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 18px;
  float: left;
}

.subtile-right {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 18px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="subtitles">
    <div class="subtile-left"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i> 137 Running Days </div>
    <div class="subtile-left"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i> Admin@superbtc.biz </div>
    <div class="subtile-right"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Deposit </div>
    <div class="subtile-right"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Paidout </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

A better way would be to consider flexbox to avoid having the whitespace issue between inline-block elements:

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: #CEECE8;
}

.subtitles {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display:flex;
}
.subtitles :nth-child(2) {
  margin-right:auto;
}

.subtile-left {
  padding-left: 18px;
}

.subtile-right {
  padding-left: 18px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="subtitles">
    <div class="subtile-left"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i> 137 Running Days </div>
    <div class="subtile-left"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i> Admin@superbtc.biz </div>
    <div class="subtile-right"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Deposit </div>
    <div class="subtile-right"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Paidout </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Elements are floated in order of source appearance.

Check this example:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.container::after { /* clearfix */
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

[id] {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 3px dotted #999;
  text-align: center;
  width: 2em;
}

#a {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
  <div id="c">C</div>
</div>
```

`div#a` floats right, which means it is moved as far to the right of its container as possible.

Now let's make `div#b` float to the right as well:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.container::after { /* clearfix */
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

[id] {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 3px dotted #999;
  text-align: center;
  width: 2em;
}

#a,
#b {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
  <div id="c">C</div>
</div>
```

Now when the layout engine parses the layout, the first element that is floated is `div#a` (because it comes before `div#b` in the source), moving it to the very right side of `div.container`.

Next comes `div#b`, which is now also floated to the right. Since `div#a` is already taking space at the right side of `div.container`, `div#b` can only float until its right border touches the left border of `div#a`.

This obviously makes it so visual appearance of `div#a` and `div#b` is inverted compared to source order.

Answer (score 1):

When the viewport is rendering the HTML it reads the elements from top bottom.

This means the following:

1) 'Deposit' is seen before 'Paidout' and thus is floated to the right part of the container div first
2) Paidout is seen and floats to the right, but bumps into deposit and thus finds its place to the left of it

[image: Poorly drawn image displaying top-bottom elements in HTML in queue and being removed and pushed into a rotated stack]